# Change Slug of a Custom Post Type

Tags: custom-post-types, functions, slug

I use a plugin that creates a custom post type with a slug that I am wanting to change. I don't want to overwrite the plugin files, so I'm wondering how I can change the slug using a separate function? Thanks.

```
// Register post type
add_action( 'init', 'ctc_register_post_type_item' );
function ctc_register_post_type_item() {
    // Arguments
    $args = array(
        'labels' => array(
                'name'                  => _x( 'items', 'post type general name', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'singular_name'         => _x( 'item', 'post type singular name', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'add_new'               => _x( 'Add New', 'item', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'add_new_item'          => __( 'Add Item', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'edit_item'             => __( 'Edit Item', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'new_item'              => __( 'New Item', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'all_items'             => __( 'All Items', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'view_item'             => __( 'View Item', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'search_items'          => __( 'Search Items', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'not_found'             => __( 'No items found', 'church-theme-content' ),
                'not_found_in_trash'    => __( 'No items found in Trash', 'church-theme-content' )
        ),
        'public'        => ctc_feature_supported( 'items' ),
        'has_archive'   => ctc_feature_supported( 'items' ),
        'rewrite'       => array(
                'slug'          => 'items',
                'with_front'    => false,
                'feeds'         => ctc_feature_supported( 'items' )
        ),
        'supports'      => array( 'title', 'editor', 'excerpt', 'publicize', 'thumbnail', 'comments', 'author', 'revisions' ), // 'editor' required for media upload button (see Meta Boxes note below about hiding)
        'taxonomies'    => array( 'ctc_item_topic', 'ctc_item_book', 'ctc_item_series', 'ctc_item_speaker', 'ctc_item_tag' ),
        'menu_icon'     => 'dashicons-video-alt3'
    );

    $args = apply_filters( 'ctc_post_type_item_args', $args ); // allow filtering

    // Registration
    register_post_type(
        'ctc_item',
        $args
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In the code you posted, the filter `ctc_post_type_item_args` gets applied to the `$args` array before it is passed into `register_post_type()`.

Putting a function into your themes `functions.php` and hooking it to the filter should do the trick:

```
function wpse_191003_ctc_post_type_item_args( $args ) {
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = "your_new_slug";
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'ctc_post_type_item_args', 'wpse_191003_ctc_post_type_item_args' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Tom's answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/42164/1878) on a similar question. He hooks into an action that adds a rewrite rule to the database so the post is accessible through both slugs. He was not actually able to redeclare the slug, but he shows how you can hide the old slug so that it appears the new one is the right one.

Another [option suggested by Dustin](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/redeclare-change-slug-of-a-plugins-custom-post-type#comment129915_41988) is to call `register_post_type` with the same $post_type but set the slug to the one you want. It sees to work for him, but no one else has confirmed if it throws problems down the line.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! Tom's answer does work to add an additional slug but the links on my site still point to the original slug, so essentially I do need to find a way to overwrite the slug. The code I mentioned above does have a filter in it: 

    $args = apply_filters( 'ctc_post_type_item_args', $args ); // allow filtering 

Does this help me at all?