# Redeclare slug & name of custom post type?

Tags: custom-post-types

I'm registering custom post type in the plugin, but want to allow users of the plugin modify it afterwards (e.g. if they are installing for clients, etc.)

```
function create_reviews_post_type() {
    register_post_type('reviews', array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __('Reviews'),
            'singular_name' => __('Review')
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'create_reviews_post_type');
```

What is best way to achieve this? 
E.g. I want to change **name**, **singular name** and **slug** in future.

I understand that there is a [similar question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/41988/redeclare-change-slug-of-a-plugins-custom-post-type), but

1. it 5 years old and I hope there can be an easier way,
2. it doesn't cover the name part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress provides the [`register_post_type_args` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/register_post_type_args/) to let users do this:

```
function wpd_modify_post_type( $args, $post_type ){
    if( 'reviews' == $post_type ){
        $args['labels']['name'] = 'New name';
        $args['labels']['singular_name'] = 'New singular name';
        $args['rewrite']['slug'] = 'new-slug';
    }
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'wpd_modify_post_type', 10, 2 );
```

Keep in mind that if the slug changes, the user will need to flush rewrite rules manually for the new slug to start working, which can be done by visiting the Settings > Permalinks page in admin.

Answer (score 3):

You could do something simple like providing them filters to modify.

```
function create_reviews_post_type() {
    $slug = apply_filters('plugin_cpt_slug','reviews');
    $name = apply_filters('plugin_cpt_name','Reviews');
    $sname = apply_filters('plugin_cpt_name_singular','Review');

    register_post_type($slug, array(
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => __($name),
            'singular_name' => __($sname)
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        )
    );
}
add_action('init', 'create_reviews_post_type');
```

They can modify them using add_filter() like so:

```
add_filter('plugin_cpt_slug','change_plugin_cpt_slug');
function change_plugin_cpt_slug(){
    return 'complaints';
}
//etc., etc.
```

This is admittedly a verbose way of doing this, but it works.

Comment: Thanks, I get the errors though: $slug, $name, $sname are undefined; register_post_type is called incorrectly

Comment: Well first of all you should change those, I used generic identifiers as an example. Change them to something more specific to your plugin. Secondly, I edited the answer.